# Undirected edges in orientDB

Tags: orientdb

I am working with orientDB v2.2.10 and I am trying to create edges of class "E" between vertices using the graph editor, my question is  can create undirected edges between vertices and if yes how to do it via Java API

Answer (score 1):

You can find documentation about graph Java API here:

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Graph-Database-Tinkerpop.html